# If I have a list of trading pairs separated by a slash, how would I make each leg a variable?

Tags: python

For instance, I have a set of trading pairs:

```
pairs = ["ETHUSDT/BTCUSDT", "VETUSDT/XMRUSDT", "ONTUSDT/ADAUSDT"]
```

Normally, if there was no slash, I'd set each variable by doing:

```
var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6 = pairs
```

How would I create individual variables when there's slashes? Also, would be interested to hear about dictionary suggestions.

Comment: You'd need to split on `/`. But is this a good idea?

Comment: `var1, ... = (j for i in pairs for j in i.split('/'))`…?

Comment: Your `pairs` is a list of results of division, nothing to split really

Comment: @Jan I'm actually using stock pairs which is why I have the slash. Separating into variables makes it easier to download ticker data later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply iterate on you array and split the data

```
pairs = ["apples/oranges", "grapes/tomatoes", "bananas/passionfruit" ,"test"]

splited_pairs = []

for pair in pairs:
    splited_pairs.extend(pair.split('/'))

print(splited_pairs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
pairs = ["apples/oranges", "grapes/tomatoes", "bananas/passionfruit"]
a, b, c, d, e, f = "/".join(pairs).split("/")
print(c)
# grapes
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/8YHTKJ).
Question remains: why? Use a `dict` or another approach altogether instead.